# 2018 Ford Edge car alarm goes off 30 seconds after arming. Sometimes

Tags: car, alarm

What type of issue would cause the car alarm to go off 30 seconds after using the key fob to arm it?

The car is a 2018 Ford Edge SE. Everything is stock. We had the dealership install add-on seat heaters when we bought it.

Ever since we've had the vehicle it has had this issue. We've had the dealership take a look at it, but with no luck. The dealer did tell me the alarm doesn't arm until 30 seconds after pushing the button on the fob. It was at that time I realized that it is always 30 seconds when the alarm goes off. It doesn't matter if the car has been sitting all day long, or if it is right after we pull into a parking lot. If we lock the doors with the key fob, 30 seconds later the alarm sometimes goes off. The alarm never goes off on it's own if it makes it past the 30 seconds.

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd be looking at the switches / wiring that indicate the doors are closed.  One of your seems to be intermittent, and when it goes south, it's telling the computer that a door is open, when its actually closed.

Comment: @zipzit This is too predictable to be a switch. The alarm never goes off at any other time. When it does, it is always 30 seconds after arming it. The car won’t let you arm the alarm if it thinks a door is open. For these reasons it doesn’t seem to be a mechanical issue.